# Java RMI ClassNotFoundException on stub occurs in Linux but not Windows

Tags: java, linux, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting the following exception when attempting to use Naming.lookup() to create an RMI object:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.server.data.RmiMainObjImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.server.data.RmiMainObjImpl_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1206)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(LoaderHandler.java:1219)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:452)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    ... 4 more
```

Curiously, this error only happens under Linux and AIX, but never under Windows.  The error happens consistently, but seemingly works under *some* versions of Java:

- The original jar was built with 1.6.0u30 on a Windows machine
- The original jar will not work under Linux using 1.7.0u60, but will work with 1.6.0u24
- The original jar will not work under AIX using 1.6 64-bit, but will work with 32-bit
- Building the jar on a Linux machine using 1.7.0u60 will actually not work with the same runtime on that machine

My policy file seems to be set up correctly and is being recognized (though, I'm guessing I'd have a different error if it was not):

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";
};
```

I'm executing java with a command line similar to this:

```
java -cp ./.:./JProjApi.jar:./MyRMI.jar -Djava.security.policy=./policy.all com/project/rmi/Main
```

And the code looks like this:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
rmiObj = (project.server.data.RmiMainObj_1_0) Naming.lookup("rmi://172.17.44.45/RMIMain");
```

I do not have access to the server-side (and I'm consuming a jar that has the necessary client-side interfaces as well).

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Naming.lookup() does not 'create an RMI object'. It *fetches* one that already exists, from the Registry. The RMI object creation all happens in the server JVM. It would be interesting to see a listing of the JAR files, and specifically where and how the stub class named in other exception appears in them. I would also check that you really have the same JAR files on all platforms concerned.

Comment: Doesn't it create the stub class that represents the server object? Semantics aside (and I'll accept if I'm totally wrong - I'm new to this), the MD5 sum for the files between RHEL and Windows matches.  That wouldn't explain why 32-bit java works on the same machine that 64-bit java doesn't, though.

Comment: As far as the stub class, it's not in the client-side jar.  I thought that the stub would be downloaded from the server?  Am I wrong about this?  If so, why does the Windows version work?  The only difference (other than the JRE itself) between the execution of Windows and Linux is that Windows uses semicolons to separate out the classpath while Linux uses colons.  That's literally it.

Comment: My JAR list is like the above command line:
1. JProjApi.jar - The client-side file 
2. MyRMI.jar - My own JAR file
3. Whatever JARs Java itself decides to add...

There's nothing else.

Comment: No, it doesn't 'create the stub class', or the stub object either. The server creates the stub object when it is exported, and binds it to the Registry. All that lookup() does is get it from the Registry. 'Listing of the JSR files' means a list of what's inside them. What they're called is of no conceivable interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuring this out became a much lower priority, but it came back.

Network scanning showed nothing unusual.

It turned out that it did, in fact, have at least something to do with the Java version or new settings on newer Java versions.

This:
-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false
Had to be added to the command line and it now works for those machines it didn't previously work on.

Answer (score 1):

> the stub class [is] not in the client-side jar.

The stub class must be in the client JAR file, unless you're using the codebase feature.

> why does the Windows version work?

If it's working on one platform and not others, the stub class is clearly in the CLASSPATH on the platforms where it works, and not in the platforms where it doesn't. Or, if you're using the codebase feature, which you haven't said anything about, the codebase URL isn't accessible from all the platforms.

Comment: I am likely using the codebase feature (unless there's no way I could be using it without knowing) -- I do know that a policy file is required or it will not work (and I seem to remember reading somewhere that the codebase feature was possibly related to this).  I don't have access to the server-side code at all, and all I have is a JAR with the interface definitions.  I had considered a network issue, but that doesn't explain why 32 bit worked and 64 bit did not on one OS.  I'll have to delve deeper into the network theory, I guess.  Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't know if you were using the codebase feature. It's controlled from the server most of the time. It might be worth sniffing outbound HTTP traffic to that server to shine some light in it. Or they could be specifying a codebase URL that doesn't work from your client, e.g. a file: URL to a shared drive that you can't see.